# iOS calculator project free to include in apps?

Tags: ios, calculator

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any existing calculator project or library that has a basic calculator view I can push into a navigation stack. So far I haven't found anything that doesn't look like junk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should find everything you need there :

http://code.google.com/p/hpcalc-iphone/

http://blog.itopchiyev.com/2008/10/09/hello-iphone/

http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/25/simple-calculator/

https://github.com/rargulati/Simple-Obj-C-Calculator

http://code.google.com/p/obj-c-calculator/source/browse/?r=30#svn%2Fbranches%2FCalculator%20at%20Assignment%201%253Fstate%253Dclosed

http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=694

You would probably have to adapt some of these in a final app. Check for copyrights, and if one get your heart but cannot be included in your project (do not hesitate to contact the authors, really), rewrite yours from scratch with that inspiration source.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [iPhoneCalculator](https://github.com/oscardelben/iPhoneCalculator) on GitHub, or [search for it by keyname](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=Objective-C&q=Calculator&repo=&langOverride=&x=22&y=11&start_value=1).

Comment: So far all the ones I see aren't complete, or look like junk. I was hoping to find one that looks/work like you could insert it into an app with no/very little change needed

Comment: As a Developer, you will need to get used to writing your own classes and designing your own interface. This is what will set you apart from  the other 1000's of Developers. This is a good starting point. If you want something more custom, then you can either feed off of this project *(which I would recommend)*. Or create your own Calculator sub project from scratch.